# C# Higher-order function to reverse the order of arguments

Tags: c#, lambda, syntax, functional-programming

I am reading the book Functional Programming in C# by Enrico Buonanno (great book).

There is one example for swapping the order of arguments, namely:

```
static Func<T2, T1, R> 
     SwapArgs<T1, T2, R>(this Func<T1, T2, R> f) => (t2, t1) => f(t1, t2);
```

Can someone please explain why is the `=>` used twice? For example, a function for diving would be written as

`Func<int, int, int> divide = (x,y) => x / y;`

The order is: function name followed by `=` followed by arguments followed by `=>` followed by the function body.
That is what is confusing me, in the `SwapArgs` we don't have `=` we have twice `=>`.

Could someone please clarify this?

Comment: The first `=>` defines `SwapArgs` and could be replace with `{ return ` ... `; }` instead, so `static Func<T2, T1, R> SwapArgs<T1, T2, R>(this Func<T1, T2, R>) { return (t2, t1) => f(t1, t2); }`. The second `=>` is shorthand for creating an anonymous method.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is needlessly costly due to creating multiple method invocations (and an allocation for the closure) solely for the purpose of swapping argument order. I really wouldn't recommend doing something like this in real code.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @NetMage! Also thanks @alexei-levenkov for redirecting me to the answers of my question.

Comment: @DavidL yes of course, this is for the demonstration purpose, as the author is explaining the higher-order functions. Thanks for the suggestion though!